# Get Holidays List of a Country from Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to extract some country's holiday list from Google Calendar API using JavaScript.

Is it Possible? How Can I do this?

Comment: I don't believe google holds list of holidays for different countries in any API. You can find public calendars with country specific holidays though.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, using Google API you can do that.

- Create an API app in the [google developer account](https://console.developers.google.com)
- From the "Credentials" tab you can create an API key, you get
  something like this `AIzaSyBcOT_DpEQysiwFmmmZXupKpnrOdJYAhhM`
- Then, you can access holidays calendar using this URL

  `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.uk%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=<YOUR API KEY>`

Comment: How to get another country's Calendar list ??

Comment: Replace the calender name on the url. 

 If you want an indian holiday calender you can see all available holiday calenders in following url : [link](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render#settings-dir_10%7Choliday)

, subscribe the indian calendar(You can choose what you want) then you can find the calendar name from the calender settings (like this : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z6S6GtWL9sfzeVu4CzH7dMCLd0IFNVzi/view).

, replace it on the url (like this : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VbsAhQaPiU0OUGnGRs19EaRANOwaltDh/view)

Comment: hi @Midhun1993, i followed your approach. But i'm keep seeing the "Login Required" message. Please help to advise: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wQ8FZPTzDXpZxvDAKNiUDKHqJeniynhd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this may not be directly connected to the question, but is there an API where we could get the list of country codes... like I would want to display the countries (code) to a select dropdown. The user could then select which could he/she wants to use to get the list of holidays.

Comment: Hi @BorgyManotoy  i think this:  https://restcountries.eu/ will help you. Please check

Comment: thanks Midhun1993, but I think I needed the list of countries that I could use in the api (in your answer). Currently tested it with `us`, `uk`, `singapore`, `china`, `indian`, `philippines`, `spain`... but there are still a lot of countries which I want to use but don't know the value to supply in the API call. This is why I wanted to get the list of countries (code) that I could use in calling this API. Thanks

Comment: looks like the link has changed. I'm getting an 404.

Comment: Yes same - I'm going to go and look at the documentation.

Comment: This works great for countries. Currently the API returns holidays for 3 years `past one year`, `current year` and `future year` for the specified country. Is there a way to get a particular year in past or in future?

Comment: @nishant have you gotten any solution?

Comment: List of calendar countries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833844/get-holidays-list-of-a-country-from-google-calendar-api

Answer (score 8):

google provides API for holiday list.

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.uk%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=YourApiKey

1. like we want holiday list for USA

then, change this text in url

```
calendars/en.usa
```

Example :-
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=YourApiKey

after this,

2. we get all Holiday event list in "items" Array.

like this,

```
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3101513576000000\"",
   "id": "20200101_60o30dr46oo30c1g60o30dr56g",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAyMDAxMDFfNjBvMzBkcjQ2b28zMGMxZzYwbzMwZHI1NmcgZW4udXNhI2hvbGlkYXlAdg",
   "created": "2019-02-21T13:46:28.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-02-21T13:46:28.000Z",
   "summary": "New Year's Day",
   "creator": {
    "email": "en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "Holidays in United States",
    "self": true
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "Holidays in United States",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "date": "2020-01-01"
   },
   "end": {
    "date": "2020-01-02"
   },
   "transparency": "transparent",
   "visibility": "public",
   "iCalUID": "20200101_60o30dr46oo30c1g60o30dr56g@google.com",
   "sequence": 0
  },
  {
.........
```

we will get all detail in there like,
Holiday name of day in "summary" key

```
"summary": "New Year's Day",
```