# Unable to retrieve holidays using Google API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

As part of an app I am working on, I would like to provide a list of holidays.  I am attempting to use the Google API to do this.  Before writing the code, I just want to have a look at what the JSON that is returned looks like.

I set up an account in Google, got an API key, and got set up to use the Google Calendar API.  I did research on the HTML needed to get a list of holidays, but cannot seem to get it to work.  I went through all of the Calendar API documentation and did not find anything about retrieving a list of holidays.  Here are some of the URLs that I tried, and the responses that I received.  I found all of these URL examples online (mostly here).  I've removed my API key.

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.uk%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=myKey

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "message": "Not Found"
        }
        ],
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.sa%40holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=myKey

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "message": "Not Found"
        }
        ],
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.uk%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=myKey

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "message": "Not Found"
        }
        ],
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.uk@holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=myKey

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "message": "Not Found"
        }
        ],
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=myKey

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "required",
            "message": "Login Required",
            "locationType": "header",
            "location": "Authorization"
        }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Login Required"
    }
}
```

Google is seeing my requests, and they are all errors.

[image]

It seems like the URLs that I've found online might have worked at one time, but no longer seem to work.

Is there any update on how to use this?

Update: I tried the information on the answer below and now I get this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I tried `en.danish#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com` in the Try This API section of the Events:List API reference and I was able to get the JSON for the dates.  I do not understand why it works in Try This API, but it is not working from url.  The latest url that I tried:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.danish#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=myKey

Comment: Have you tried the solution in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833844/get-holidays-list-of-a-country-from-google-calendar-api/43783619)?

Comment: Yes.  That's where I got one of the URLs that I listed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug in the api currently.  Public apis should be accessible using an API key they are not anymore you need to be authenticated

[bug report here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124589446)

**Bug verification information**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.danish%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

If you use Oauth2 and authenticate yourself you get

```
{

 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"2IG_UfzQLHbZ3_DsNnNPPvIpYxU/iF_yglNpjvUgQba3YfGrk5JFgq4\"",
 "id": "en.danish#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
 "summary": "Holidays in Denmark",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
 "conferenceProperties": {
  "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
   "eventHangout"
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried generating a new key and it didn't make any difference.  I've updated my original post with the results of trying this answer.  Getting closer, I think.

Comment: What I don't understand is that on the Try This API page, when I select "use an api key to authorize your request", it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by url encoding the `#` and `@` in the Public Calendar ID.

In my case:

```
en.new_zealand#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com
```

becomes:

```
en.new_zealand%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events
```

Until I did that, I was receiving a 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works but without the language in front of the country.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/uk%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=YOURKEY
```

Which is annoying for non english speaking countries like mine.